# Three threads.T1 print 1,4,7.. messages sequence T2 print 2,5,8.. and T3 print 3,6,9.. How do I synchronize these three to print 1-15 message sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronous

```
public class Chat {
int flag=0;

public synchronized void Friend1(String msg) {
 if(flag>0) {
     try {
         wait();
     }
     catch(InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
 System.out.println(msg);
 flag=1;
 notify();
 }

public synchronized void Friend2(String msg) {
if(flag==0) {
    try {
        wait();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println(msg);
flag=0;
notify();
}
public synchronized void Friend3(String msg) {
if(flag<0) {
    try {
        wait();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println(msg);
flag=(-1);
notify();
}
}


public class T1 implements Runnable {
Chat m;
String[] s1= {"Hi","How are you all?","Why what happened","Yes, We are in a hectic situation but we have to continue our studies and be strong inside","Fave faith in Allah! Eveything will be ok"};

public T1(Chat m1) {
    this.m=m1;
    new Thread(this, "Friend1").start();
    }
public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length; i++) {
        m.Friend1(s1[i]);
    }
}
}


public class T2 implements Runnable{
Chat m;
String[] s2= {"Hy","I am fine","Is there anything wrong?","There is nothing we can do about in this pandemic situation but to study and pray","Everything will be fine soon"};

public T2(Chat m2) {
    this.m=m2;
    new Thread(this, "Answer").start();
    }
public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<s2.length; i++) {
        m.Friend2(s2[i]);
    }
}
}
public class T3 implements Runnable {
Chat m;
String[] s3= {"Hello","I am not fine","I am very depressed about my online classes","I feel too much preassure","Yeap I will start praying to Allah that everything comes around"};

public T3(Chat m3) {
    this.m=m3;
    new Thread(this, "Friends3").start();
    }
public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<s3.length; i++) {
        m.Friend3(s3[i]);
    }
}
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Chat m=new Chat();
new T1(m);
new T2(m);
new T3(m);
   }
   }
```

Output is:
Hi

Hy

How are you all?

I am fine

Why what happened

Is there anything wrong?

Yes, We are in a hectic situation but we have to continue our studies and be strong inside

There is nothing we can do about in this pandemic situation but to study and pray

Fave faith in Allah! Eveything will be ok

Everything will be fine soon

Hello

Comment: I have added the message in each of the threads using String want to read it one after another sequentially.

Comment: can you remove all religious text please? and add the comment to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you know that every thread should print phrase after previous:

- 2 after 1
- 3 after 2
- 1 after 3

So you can create variable that will be store number of the thread that shouldmake action now:

```
AtomicInteger currentSpeaker = new AtomicInteger(1);
```

Every thread can check this var before printing next phrase and set new value for next thread:

```
public class T1 implements Runnable {
    Chat m;
    String[] s1 = {"Hi", "How are you all?", "Why what happened", "Yes, We are in a hectic situation but we have to continue our studies and be strong inside", "Fave faith in Allah! Eveything will be ok"};

    public T1(Chat m1) {
        this.m = m1;
        new Thread(this, "Friend1").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
            while (currentSpeaker.get() != 1) delay(100L);
            m.Friend1(s1[i]);
            currentSpeaker.set(2);
        }
    }
}


public class T2 implements Runnable {
    Chat m;
    String[] s2 = {"Hy", "I am fine", "Is there anything wrong?", "There is nothing we can do about in this pandemic situation but to study and pray", "Everything will be fine soon"};

    public T2(Chat m2) {
        this.m = m2;
        new Thread(this, "Answer").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
            while (currentSpeaker.get() != 2) delay(100L);
            m.Friend2(s2[i]);
            currentSpeaker.set(3);
        }
    }
}

public class T3 implements Runnable {
    Chat m;
    String[] s3 = {"Hello", "I am not fine", "I am very depressed about my online classes", "I feel too much preassure", "Yeap I will start praying to Allah that everything comes around"};

    public T3(Chat m3) {
        this.m = m3;
        new Thread(this, "Friends3").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < s3.length; i++) {
            while (currentSpeaker.get() != 3) delay(100L);
            m.Friend3(s3[i]);
            currentSpeaker.set(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I created method delay to make code little clear for reading:

```
public static void delay(long t) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(t);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Output:

> Hi
>
> Hy
>
> Hello
>
> How are you all?
>
> I am fine
>
> I am not fine
>
> Why what happened
>
> Is there anything wrong?
>
> I am very depressed about my online classes
>
> Yes, We are in a hectic situation but we have to continue our studies
> and be  strong inside
>
> There is nothing we can do about in this pandemic situation but to
> study and pray
>
> I feel too much preassure
>
> Fave faith in Allah! Eveything will be ok
>
> Everything will be fine soon
>
> Yeap I will start praying to Allah that everything comes around

Comment: can you be more specific about in which part of the code should I make changes.

Comment: You can create currentSpeaker variable in any accessible by threads place (e.g public static or variable from common parent class).
Also edit your threads as I wrote in post - check current speaker number before phrase and update after.
I published all code that you need to use.

Comment: Do I need to make any changes in the chat class or the main class???? I have used currentSpeaker variable and delay method in T1, T2 and T3 and also updated them according to your codes but not getting the output like yours. My output is Hi, Hy and Hello

Comment: No, you don't need to edit anything else. Pls check again if you updates  currentSpeaker correctly. Your input looks like first thread still waiting after third thread printed phrase. You can share your code if you want.

Comment: for T1 AtomicInteger currentSpeaker = new AtomicInteger(1);. for T2 AtomicInteger currentSpeaker = new AtomicInteger(2); for T3 AtomicInteger currentSpeaker = new AtomicInteger(1); and also added delay void in T1 T2 and T3 and updated everything according to your code

Comment: You don't need to create currentSpeaker variable for each thread. It should be one for all threads. That's the whole point - all threads should be checking one variable and manage their actions depending on it.